# PowerShell Move-item not moving everything

Tags: powershell

Im currently running a script with task scheduler to move items from one folder to another, on occasion it doesn't seem to be moving every item across.

When I check it manually the Get-childitem, selects all the required folders I want to move, so a bit stumped on why only some folders are moving.

I was thinking, I would be able to create a loop of the `move-item` to keep cycling through the folder until no folders that match is found. Any ideas on how I would go about this.

or if there is a better route?

---

the variable to the path is set with the below

```
#Select date range
$enGB = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")
$GBdate = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -Format "yyyyMMdd"

#Locates file
$filelog = Get-childitem "C:\Logs\$GBdate*"
```

and the move item is...

```
#creates local folder
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "F:\Logs\$GBdate$("Logs")" 

#moves files to new folder
Move-Item -Path $filelog -Destination "F:\Logs\$GBdate$("Logs")" -Force
```

Comment: Why not just configure the scheduled task to run more frequently?

Comment: The script is a lot larger than the above code, and its performs multiple actions that I would not like to be repeated. 

it's only the move-item section that seems to be impacting it. any ideas on how I can approach this?

Comment: They look like log files - are you certain the system writing the logs has finished with that folder? You can’t move a file that’s locked (or a directory that contains a locked file). Check your script is displaying any errors that happen in case that’s the cause…

Comment: @mclayton - I think you have hit the nail on the head here. I have run a foreach {...} on the files and certain ones are returning (because it is being used by another process). I have delayed the process by a day to give it time to unlock the file.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
# Locates files and directories
# if C:\Logs\$GBdate is a directory, use "C:\Logs\$GBdate\*"
$filelog = Get-childitem "C:\Logs\$GBdate*"

# Prepare the name of the destination directory
$Destination = "F:\Logs\$GBdate$("Logs")" 

#creates local folder
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Destination

#moves files to new folder
$FileLog | Move-Item -Destination $Destination
```

or, as One-Line alternative:
`Get-childitem "C:\Logs\$GBdate*" -File | Move-Item -Destination "F:\Logs\$GBdate$("Logs")"`